# How do I uninstall an Addon added by running a Python Script?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I tried to install the CreaPrim script and I ran the script 3 times due to confusion on my part, but the result is that now I have 3 CreaPrim sections in my Tools panel:

[image]

How can I get rid of 2 of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can uninstall it as you didn't technically install it if you said you 'ran the script'. Best you can do is close and re-open file I think.

**Edit:**

I found that the script had also been added to my startup file without me having saved it. On windows I navigated to:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.70\scripts\addons\__pycache__\
```

I deleted a file with `object_creaprim` in the file name and reloaded blender and it disappeared.

Comment: Unfortunately, I seem to have unwittingly saved it to my startup file. Is there any way I can get rid of just 2 instances of the CreaPrim? My startup file has all my personalized settings and I don't want to have to delete it and then go through resetting ALL those many many settings I like.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all I needed to do was to quit Blender and the scripts I'd run that made all 3 of those Create Primitive sections went away. I had been reloading my startup file, but that didn't get rid of them. Anyway, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd>

F8 is the default shortcut to the `Reload Scripts` operator, which as the name suggests will reload all scripts as if blender has just been re-started.